# Completely disable audio jack as a media output

Tags: settings, audio

I bought 3.5 mm. dust plug jack and I'm using its buttons, but Android is considering it as a headphone and always routing the audio to it not the phone speakers nor the Bluetooth. I need to completely disable it as a media output. Please advise or guide where to ask. Stackoverflow, Super User, XDA, Android Central or Reddit. My phone is rooted and ready for any solution.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! A related question you might wish to look at: [Is it possible to direct all audio output, including music output, to a Bluetooth headset?](/q/19336/16575) Faizan's answer with SoundAbout should apply to your use-case (see [these posts](/search?q=soundabout) for some additional examples).

Comment: Thank you, but Soundabout crash on my phone. Note 8 running Oreo.

Comment: Sad to hear. The app was last updated about 2 years ago (i.e. before Oreo), so it indeed could be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://plus.google.com/100255718384858554176/posts/Bqp8GtkQY9x Mr Ian Grody had posted a solution to be done by tasker and Lesser audio manager.

Edit for in case the link was changed.

You need to send Lesser AudioSwitch intents and it'll switch between headphones and speaker..
By Tasker.

LAIH (232)
    A1: Send Intent [ Action:com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch.HEADPHONES Cat:None Mime Type: Data: Extra: Extra: Extra: Package:com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch Class:com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch.SoundBroadcastReceiver Target:Broadcast Receiver ]

LAIS (233)
    A1: Send Intent [ Action:com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch.SPEAKER Cat:None Mime Type: Data: Extra: Extra: Extra: Package:com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch Class:com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch.SoundBroadcastReceiver Target:Broadcast Receiver ] 
Edited for

Answer (score 0):

In android oreo, users can choose where to output the audio on the notification bar. Another way to do this is to destroy your phone audio jack by opening up your phone and unplugging the wires from the motherboard. There might be also root methods like xposed framework or something similar to map the audio output.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I just need to swap the default audio output when that smart button "headphone jack similar to Pressy" is plugged in to the phone speakers not the headset or headphone. Sure there's a such options in mixerpath or mixergain files but I'm not a programmer :( if only a shell script, command or even to edit those related system files I'll do it.